# joda time 1900 issue

Tags: java, jodatime

`date` is `1900-01-01`.

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = ISODateTimeFormat.date();
return fmt.withZone(DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(zone)).print(date.getTime());
```

the output is `1899-12-31`. why this error? how to fix it?

Comment: Well, what is `zone`? It's probably GMT minus something, and that's why you're going back a day.

Answer (score 3):

There's 30 min difference at `1900-01-01` between java's `Date` and joda's `DateTime`. (`java.sql.Date` is subclass of `java.util.Date`)

So, this is not a formatter problem. Investigate the following code and check the output:

```
Date javaDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("1900-01-01");
System.out.printf("%s,  %d\n", javaDate, javaDate.getTime());

DateTime jodaDate1 = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
System.out.printf("%s, %d\n", jodaDate1, jodaDate1.getMillis());

DateTime jodaDate2 = new DateTime(javaDate.getTime());
System.out.printf("%s,  %d\n", jodaDate2, jodaDate2.getMillis());
```

When you check the output, you can see that the same millisecond values are represented as different date. If you change the date to `1900-01-02`, the dates and their millisecond values are the same.

Therefore, it seems that you should extract each field from java's `Date` and create a joda's `DateTime` instance using the field values, like the following:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(javaDate);
DateTime dt = new DateTime(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), 
                           cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1,
                           cal.get(Calendar.DATE), 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: the date is java.sql.Date. if it's timezone difference, why all other dates print is correct?

Comment: @user1693380 Which timezone do you use?

Comment: jdk date and joda datetime both use +8 timezone.

Comment: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.joda-time.user/310 someone said having this issues. but not in datetimeformatter.